# How to zip and unzip xlsx files programatically in objective-c with zlib/gzip but not ZipArchive?

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a zip folder of xlsx file and unzip or extract the xml files in the xlsx file programmatically(in Objective-C) using zlib/gzip.Is it possible?I do not want to use ZipArchive class.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download and compile the [minizip source files](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) and create a static library that will do what you want.

Comment: I have zlib 1.2.3 installed.I have written this method to use inflate methos of zlib.I can see that data is decompressed by comparing the size of input and the output file generated.But I want the xml files in xlsx to be extracted into a folder.

Comment: @PriyaAnand Which is where minizip comes in; it provides the archiving to go along with the compression (which is all zlib provides).

Comment: Oh Is there any example illustarting this?I have an xlsx file written into an NSMutableData object([dataObj initWithContentsOfFile:XYZ.xlsx).I then use inflate and deflate on it.I see that the [dataObj length] is varied after inflate and deflate.How do I extraxt the xml files into a folder?Kindly help me with some sample code.TIA